# How are Root CA Certificate Lifecycles handled at a large scale?

Tags: encryption

From my research, it sounds as though a root certificate store is completely managed by your operating system. Which is to say, if I install software, or updates to the OS or browsers (or anything possibly) then my root ca store can be updated with new trusted roots. Assuming i am running as sudo, root, or admin on windows.

Isn't this a major problem for MITM attacks where a software package could re route both my default dns and install a root ca cert to hijack all internet connections?

The more salient question is how are root ca certificates managed from start to finish?

If you were hosting your own pki for internal use and have your own internal dns servers for your hosts. How would you push your trusted root to your devices? How would you update them? revoke them?

What happens to IOT devices that perhaps do not offer an interface to manage their root ca store?

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't this a major problem for MITM attacks where a software package could re route both my default dns and install a root ca cert to hijack all internet connections?

No, because if malware has the level of access in your system needed to install a new root CA, it could already be stealing all of your data without needing to do that.

Comment: Granted, but every time you install software as an administrator, this is a threat? All you internet traffic can be MITM all the time without your knowledge? unless you manually check the ssl certificates on sites?

Comment: @John00000000000 If you install software as an administrator, you need to be sure beforehand that it's not malicious. If it is, you can kiss all your private data goodbye, even if you do manually check the SSL certificates on every site you visit afterwards.

Comment: How can one be sure that the software is not malicious? I guess you can never be sure.